# How do I use onchange to make a changes to which list is shown (show/hide) by using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

This is my dropdown.

```
<select id="sortBySelector" onchange="chooseSort(value)" style="display:block;border-color: #e0e0e0;">
                    <option value="nameSort" selected>Alphabetical</option>
                    <option value="gradSort">Graduation Date</option>


                </select>
```

I have two `<ul>` with id= "nameSort" and "gradSort"
I wrote jquery code that will show only the selected one.
I tried this

```
<script>
function chooseSort(value) {
    $("#nameSort").hide();
    $("#gradSort").hide();
    $(value).show();


}`
```

but it shows both lists when its on the Alphabetical option and shows nothing when i click on the Graduation option. Im not sure why this is happening. Please let me know if you can help. thank you for your time

Comment: Can you post the rest of your HTML code?  I see that you tried, but only a portion showed up.  This will help greatly!

Comment: Which part do you want to look at

Comment: As far as I'm conserned `hide()` doesn't work on options. Your best bet if you want to hide the options(I don't understand why you need it though, you won't be able to select again since one option will be hidden) is to wrap them with spans and hide those spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value itself will represent the actual value of `option`. So if the selected `option` value be `gradSort` this part of your code

```js
$(value).show();
```

will be pointed to

```js
$("gradSort").show();
```

**which is not refer to anything in DOM**. Because it is not a valid selector *(tag)*, so to make this work, you should add `#` either

**before your query selector**

```js
$('#' + value).show();
```

or **before the value of your options**.

```html
<option value="#nameSort" selected>Alphabetical</option>
<option value="#gradSort">Graduation Date</option>
```

I will go with the query selector choice, so it will be something like this:

```js
function chooseSort(value) {
  $("#nameSort").hide();
  $("#gradSort").hide();
  $("#" + value).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  chooseSort("nameSort");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sortBySelector" onchange="chooseSort(value)" style="display:block;border-color: #e0e0e0;">
  <option value="nameSort" selected>Alphabetical</option>
  <option value="gradSort">Graduation Date</option>
</select>

<div id="nameSort">nameSort</div>
<div id="gradSort">gradSort</div>
```

Comment: how do i make sure that upon opening the page that namesort is automatically selected? I tried the selected tag but nothing seems to happen

Comment: @TerriSong You just have to call your function once on page load. Just like this `chooseSort("nameSort");`

Answer (score 1):

Consider what this is doing with the given value:

```
$(value).show();
```

If the value is `gradSort` then you're doing:

```
$("gradSort").show();
```

Which is an incorrect selector.  If you're looking by `id` then it's missing the `#` at the beginning.  You can add that to the values:

```
<option value="#nameSort" selected>Alphabetical</option>
<option value="#gradSort">Graduation Date</option>
```

Or, if for a reason outside of this you don't want to change the values, you can add it to the string in the selector:

```
$('#' + value).show();
```

or:

```
$(`#${value}`).show();
```

> it shows both lists when its on the Alphabetical option

It sounds like it shows both lists when the page *first loads*.  If that's the case you can just call the function manually on page load to set the initial state:

```
chooseSort('#nameSort');
```

or:

```
chooseSort('nameSort');
```

(depending on which solution you used above)

Answer (score 0):

You need a conditional to determine which will be shown and which will stay hidden.  There are a few different ways to do this but I would do it like so:

```
<select id="sortBySelector" onchange="chooseSort(value)" style="display:block;border-color: #e0e0e0;">
                    <option id="nameSort' value="nameSort" selected>Alphabetical</option>
                    <option id="gradSort value="gradSort">Graduation Date</option>


                </select>
```

```
function chooseSort(value) {
  if (value === 'nameSort'){
        $('#' + value).show(); // $("#nameSort").show(); would work
        $("#gradSort").hide();
    } else{
        $('#' + value).show(); // $("#gradSort").show(); would work
        $("#nameSort").hide();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works!

EDIT: In the spirit of keeping your HTML the same, I did have to add the id to each option to make it work.  Also, I had to redo the `value.show()`

Comment: how would you implement this if you were to use switch?

Comment: It works for the second tag but you need to preselect the first option in order for it to work.